# Http user agent parser in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, http-headers, user-agent

i wanted to parse the User Agent string in the python and classify the browser in the following categories as
1) Browser name 
2) Browser version 
3) OS/Platform name 
4) OS/Platform version 
5) Device Type : either mobile/desktop/tablet/other 
If its mobile/tablet then 
6) Manufaturer/Vendor Name 
7) Model No

So, what external library can i use to achieve this task and i wanted to do all this stuff offline without any internet connection. So i have a database i just need to classify it.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/user-agents/

Comment: @root : i have seen this but i also wanted to know the mobile/tablet vendor like nokia,samsung,blackberry etc and even their model no from those user_agent string

Comment: it is based on the [ua-parser](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser), if it doesn't fit your needs you can try to improve it. not sure if you will find something that will do everything out of the box, but good luck finding it.

Comment: firstly its regular expression are complicated and how to include all vendor and make their regular expression. secondly, i wanted to simply include the library and make it work so that i can update library from internt from time to time and make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import the lib
from ua_parser import user_agent_parser

# Parse the user agent
user_agent_parser.Parse(request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT'))

print result_dict['user_agent']
# {'major': '5', 'minor': '1', 'family': 'Mobile Safari', 'patch': None}

print result_dict['os']
# {'major': '5', 'patch_minor': None, 'minor': '1', 'family': 'iOS', 'patch': None}

print result_dict['device']
# {'is_spider': False, 'is_mobile': True, 'family': 'iPhone'}
```

The code samples above are all easily recognizable by those who can use them; using     user agent information is simple, and the API is as well. Well done to Tobie for this nice   library.

http://davidwalsh.name/user-agent-parser

Comment: thanx, it will work out to some extent for me but i also wanted the model no like if its iPhone then whether it is iPhone 4 or iPhone 5, similarly for other manufacturer and their model no.

Answer (score -1):

This is not about an open source solution to the question, but a solution bevertheless.

Are you guys aware of [the WURFL Module for Python](https://docs.scientiamobile.com/documentation/infuze/infuze-python-module-user-guide)?